# No decimal input on numeric field when using Google Sheets on phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, when I add a number (e.g. `1.01`) using the text keyboard and hit Enter, this numeric keyboard pops up as a default because the field is numeric. However, I do not have a decimal option, so I switch back to text keyboard, and we start over *on every cell*... or I could switch back and forth *just to get the decimal*, which is also insane.

On a tablet, in the white (extra options) the last one is the decimal point, but on the phone, it isn't there. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 and there is no decimal point on numeric keyboard.

How to input a decimal point with numeric keyboard?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: What is your device model? And what keyboard are you using? It seems it's impossible to do (1) and not sure about (2), so do you mind changing keyboard?

Comment: I'm quite sure the Google Keyboard, SwiftKey and ai.type keyboard apps have the decimal point. Use any one of them. The 1st 2 are free.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury This is also what I was thinking and a great suggestion. Perhaps add this as an answer if the keyboards show the decimal point by default on the numeric keypad. Be sure to include Play Store links!

Comment: @Great answer! Don't worry about pictures...

Comment: @AndrewT. Samsung Galaxy S 3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was fixed after app software update

Comment: What software update? OS or app? Clarify and state relevant versions and other information if possible.

Answer (score 4):

There may not be an exact solution to the problem *as you posted it*, but there are possible workarounds. Android's primary strength is it's customizability and modularity, so if one (your stock) keyboard does not satisfy you, you're welcome to switch it out for another which does.

I know of 3 keyboard apps off-hand that have a decimal point in their numeric keypad. These are:

1. [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) - The officially recommended keyboard app for Android, and the default for Nexus devices and devices running Lollipop or above (as the AOSP keyboard). Very clean and doesn't deviate much from AOSP. Completely free.
2. [SwiftKey Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en) - a very popular keyboard replacement app (some might even say *the* most popular). Highly themeable. Free with in-app purchases.
3. [ai.type Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android&hl=en) - Another very popular keyboard. Supposedly has very good text prediction, and also high themeability. Free with in-app purchases, Pro version removes ads.

I recommend these keyboard replacement apps to the OP as I have used them myself and know that they (when I used them) provided a numeric keypad with a decimal point, as the OP requires.